# Limiting use of Select * in MySQL in a specific table

Tags: mysql, security, limit

I have a table that contains some sensitive data that I would like to secure further than the measures already taken. In the event of an intrusion resulting the attacker obtaining our PHP source code I want to protect some data in the database further.

Data has already been encrypted in the database, and encryption keys safely stored outside of the source code, but unfortunately these are only delays that will hopefully give us time to discover the intrusion and shut the system down. However, a reverse engineering of the code is technically possible.

As a fail safe I would like to limit select statements against a specific table. Our code should never have a need of retrieving more than one record at a time from the table. Is there a way of limiting the number of rows returned from a table from an administrative side of MySQL so that queries such as SELECT * FROM secure_data_table; are not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way of limiting the number of rows returned from a table from an administrative side of MySQL

The common way to do this is to DENY access to the table.

Create a stored procedure that selects one item from the table, e.g. by ID, and GRANT access to only that proc.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html ):

```
 GRANT priv_type [(column_list)] [, priv_type [(column_list)] ...]
     ON {tbl_name | * | *.* | db_name.*}
     TO user_name [IDENTIFIED BY 'password']
         [, user_name [IDENTIFIED BY 'password'] ...]
     [REQUIRE
            [{SSL| X509}]
    [CIPHER cipher [AND]]
    [ISSUER issuer [AND]]
    [SUBJECT subject]]
     [WITH GRANT OPTION]
```

The only `priv_type` values you can specify for a column (that is, when
you use a `column_list` clause) are `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE`.

Comment: Putting valid links in your answer is your BEST friend.

Comment: ah, I forgot to thank you for pointing out the invalid link. Thanks again @Abe

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do this at the table level.  Obviously you can limit the number of records returned in the query it self but not at the table level.

If a malicious user gets access to your admin account then they could probably reverse such a restriction anyways (if one existed).

Answer (score 0):

Why not move your queries to the database, too (parametrized stored procedures, no table level access)?

What level of compromise are you anticipating?  At that level, is it possible to bypass anything at the schema level, by the user granting themselves any rights they would need.  At that level, does encryption matter?  Encryption means that the files or backups are secure, but typically, the database can decrypt at will.  If you have access to the PHP and you do encryption there, you are likely to have access to the key as well.

Comment: Just wanting to put in a few layers of security. Trying to implement security through planning for the unexpected. In the event that an injection style attack or php shell is successful, this means that source code may become exposed, but not necessarily database access beyond the user specified in the source code. The ability to separate or at the very least slow down the loss of sensitive information is important. Using a stored process that limits the select statement to one returned row will make it difficult to easily gain information.

Comment: @InvisibleFrisbee That's what I'm advocating.  The app should access the database with a login which only can execute stored procs, no table rights.